# how to get all images in iphone photo album

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I want get all images in iphone photo album without imagepicker.

I have seen same functions other app.

help plz~^^;

Answer (score 0):

Read and use assets library .It will answer all your questions .[link text](http://blancer.com/tutorials/i-phone/58725/asset-libraries-and-blocks-in-ios-4/)